# Unable to use Chrome Power API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to use the Chrome Power API to ensure the display stays active.

I have tried adding the following line of code to my background.js file, which failed, and also in my main app js file, which also failed

```
chrome.power.requestKeepAwake('display');
```

How exactly do I use the Power API (no exmaples in the GitHub samples, and no documentation about it, other then the above line of code, no explaination on where it should go, or anything.

EDIT - This is how I put it in my background.js, which didn't work

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.power.requestKeepAwake('display');

  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 1280,
      'height': 720
    }
  });
});
```

I get

> Error in event handler for app.runtime.onLaunched: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'power' of undefined

Comment: Define "failed". Also, which OS?

Comment: If define in my own app.js, i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'power' of undefined" also, on Windows 7 64 Bit, running Chrome 40

Comment: That error is indicating that `chrome` is undefined.. Which cannot happen. Look for typos. Are you sure it's not "Cannot read property 'requestKeepAwake' of undefined"?

Comment: I copy and pasted the message. How do I make sure "chrome" is defined, or is it by default?

Comment: Did you include the power permission in manifest.json?

Comment: Ah, damnit! that's it. Is it just me though, or is the Chrome App documentation terrible for explaining anything? ha!

Comment: @MrPablo The documentation mentions it in the very header, but does a bad job stressing it. The arcane error message does not help.

Answer (score 3):

To use the "power" API, you need to declare the proper permission, as indicated at the very beginning of [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/power):

```
"permissions" : ["power"],
```

If you don't include this, you can run into the "undefined" error.

---

However, the error you quote is *strange*. It should be

> Cannot read property 'requestKeepAwake' of undefined

Double-check for typos. I recommend deleting the whole string and re-typing it by hand (a stray Unicode unprintable character is a possibility)

Comment: The error message was correct and the code i used was copied. Turns out it was due to the permissions, which is probably why the error message was weird.

Comment: That is definitely the cause, but the error message is unexplainable. When you run into this problem, `chrome.power` is undefined, which is fine, and then you try to access a sub-property `requestKeepAwake`. That should throw the error I quoted (I specifically tested so make sure!).

Comment: No idea mate, those were 100% the messages I got.